# Is Magnetomer avaible in ReactNative for Android?

Tags: react-native

Like in the title. I saw some NPM modules for Magnetomer (like react-native-motion-manager ). The question is: will it work for Android as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wraps one of the iOS classes (`CMMotionManager`) so no.

Comment: Thanks for an answer then. I thought so but wanted a confirmation for this one. I need to do something asap in ReactNative and I need Magnetomer.